# 環境構築後、特定のアドレスへアクセスした場合にエラーが出てしまう

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

以下のリポジトリですが、自分が環境構築した際はエラーは出なかったのですが、他の方にして頂いた際に、エラーが出てしまいました。
https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site

エラー内容は以下になります
`Cannot find module './src/algoliasearch.helper'`

こちらはローカル環境実行後、 localhost:3000/ja/getting-started/introduction こちらアドレスへのアクセス後に出てしまっていたとのことでした。現在は、その対応策としてalgoliasearch-helperモジュールの使用箇所はコメントアウトしています。
お手数をおかけし恐縮ですが、他の方のご環境でどうなのか知りたい為、もし可能でしたら一度検証を行い結果を教えて頂けませんでしょうか。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 環境構築に失敗するのであれば、手順に不備があるはずです。例えば、npmを使用しているので、node.jsのバージョンを明示しましょう。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
node.jsのバージョンを追記しました。